# Connect to mysql server with one url but have multiple masters

Tags: mysql

I am looking to have one URL like `master.mydb.com`, but under the hood I want to be able to access databases on `slave1.mydb.com` or `slave2.mydb.com`.

The reason for this is we have a massive number of near identical databases on each server, but very different data on each database. kinda like this:

```
slave1.mydb.com has databases
p1
p2
p3

slave2.mydb.com has databases
p4
p5
p6
```

all of those databases will have the exact same tables in them, but when my server accesses the data I just want to be able to connect to the cluster, and not have to worry about figuring out where the database p4 is stored, and making a connection slave2-mydb.com. In production we will probably have something more like slave[1-20].mydb.com with

Comment: They are not exact duplicates. The structure of the database are all the same, but the data itself is all wildly different. I figured I would need to manage connection strings, but i was REALLY REALLY trying not to. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a replication problem to solve. Something like [spider](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/spider-storage-engine-overview/), [max scale](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-maxscale-25/) or [vitess](https://vitess.io/). Also, see the Percona toolkit for comparing tables.

Of course internally you could have some DNS based mechanism like `p5.mydb.com` to indicate these server has p5 and use this in the application's connection to the database.

If you have same databases in all slaves then you need a load balancer, which you can achieve with *haproxy, ngnix*. If you want to split read write between slave and master then you can look into *proxySQL*. If you have different databases then you need to manage that in the connection strings.